# How do i install Ubuntu alongside Windows safely in legacy hardware?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows

I want to install ubuntu alongside windows but I have legacy hardware and I have a lot of important files how do I install it safely the same thing alongside I tried on my 2nd pc it erased the whole pc is there any way to install it safely without deleting anything?

This is what I did
1st booted into installation disk
2nd created a new ext2 partition
3rd installed in it but the installation does not booted so I selected the hard disk

Comment: you need to expand your question with details about what specifically you have tried to avoid proposed solutions which you have already tried unsuccessfully. Please read askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask  and then [edit] accordingly.

Comment: ok i have edited it

Comment: hmm im thinking to do backup before installing operating system but there are a lot of files in every disk disk : https://imgur.com/a/9I00JB6

Comment: You've not provided any release or specific details about the hardware.  I use hp/dell/lenovo boxes from 2005+ (which I'd consider qualifies as *legacy*) & don't have any issues. I'd suggest preparing the partitions yourself using tools you know (even if not formatted) & use the *Something Else* or *Manual Partitioning* options of the installer to select those partitions to install into.  I'm involved in QA & know the system doesn't erase unless you tell it to, however it's easy to make mistakes so backup everything important first & read what the install will do before you install.

Comment: Also please don't forget a disk refers to the whole disk drive; which may have ONE or MORE PARTITIONS on it.  Microsoft admitted they made a mistake years ago referring to partitions as 'disks', but users didn't like them changing the terms to correct ones so Microsoft gave up.  Your drive C:, D: etc maybe partitions on the **same** disk, so an ERASE DISK option will erase ALL partition(s) on the selected disk.  A single disk may contain 1 or more partition(s) on it.  You've not provided release details or specifics about intended release, so I can't be specific as to installer you'll use.

Comment: Re-partitioning and installing a new operating system are *inherently risky*. Many folks make mistakes, and many folks erroneously delete data or format the wrong partition. A backup of any data that you value should be your first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need enough **unpartitioned free space** reserved for Ubuntu in order to install with the guided option "Install Alongside Windows".

So do not create an `ext4` partition ahead of time.  The Ubuntu installer will do that for you.

If you wish to manually partition, you will have to use the "Something Else" option, and manually set up and configure a valid, appropriate partition scheme.

Any time you are installing operating systems and manipulating partitions, there is heightened chance that you make a mistake or something does not go as planned. The chance is never zero for risk of data loss or accident so it would be a good decision to come up with a reliable permanent backup strategy.

Comment: well it worked correctly on my second PC , but I haven't tested it on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to do it safely, use 2 physical hard drives.

Install Ubuntu on the 2nd drive, and use the Bios boot device selector to keep that as the default. Ubuntu will detect the 2nd OS on the other disk and add it to Grub so you can easily boot to Windows (at least it should, this is the method I used and it did detect correctly).

This method insures there is no modification of the partition structure on the Windows boot disk.